# How to select top 3 columns/variables according to the sum values of each column?

Tags: r, select

I have a dataset like this

```
>head(grocery)

milk bread juice honey eggs beef ... (140 more variables)
  1    4     3     1    4     2
  2    5     4     2    4     3
  1    2     6     0    7     0
  0    1     5     3    3     1
  4    10    2     1    5     8
```

I want to select 3 columns that have largest sum values, showing the order, column name and sum values, and place them in descending order. Like this:

```
1 eggs  23
2 bread 22
3 juice 20
```

How can I do this?

Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: I would suggest a `gather-grouby-summarise-top_n` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(key,value) %>% 
   group_by(key) %>% 
   summarise(Sum=sum(value)) %>% 
   arrange(desc(Sum)) %>% 
   top_n(3,Sum)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  key     Sum
  <chr> <int>
1 eggs     23
2 bread    22
3 juice    20
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(milk = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 4L), bread = c(4L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 10L), juice = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 2L), honey = c(1L, 2L, 
0L, 3L, 1L), eggs = c(4L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L), beef = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 
1L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Original answer

In *base R* you can **find sums** of values for *each column*, **sort** the resulted values in *decreasing order*, **subset** *first 3 values* and `cbind` them to get the desired output:

```
cbind(sort(colSums(dat), T)[1:3])

#      [,1]
#eggs    23
#bread   22
#juice   20
```

#### Updated answer

> ...how I can go back to the original data set from this solution?...

Here I *subset* original data set by *names* corresponding to columns with three *largest columns sums*. Probably there is better solution, that one what I can find right now.

```
dat[, names(sort(colSums(dat), T)[1:3])]

#  eggs bread juice
#1    4     4     3
#2    4     5     4
#3    7     2     6
#4    3     1     5
#5    5    10     2
```

#### Data:

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "milk bread juice honey eggs beef
             1    4     3     1    4     2
             2    5     4     2    4     3
             1    2     6     0    7     0
             0    1     5     3    3     1
             4    10    2     1    5     8",
  stringsAsFactors = F,
  header           = T
)
```

Comment: Nice and simple! Do you know how I can go back to  the original  data set from this solution? For instance undo `colSums`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tiny example:

```
data <- NULL
data$c <- c(1,2,3,4)
data$b <- c(4,5,6,7)
data$a <- c(1,1,1,1)


apply(data, 2, sum)

arraysum <- NULL
for(i in names(data)){
  arraysum$name <- append(arraysum$name,i)
  arraysum$sum <- append(arraysum$sum, sum(data[[i]]))
}
arraysum$sum

arraysum$name[order(arraysum$sum, decreasing = T)]
```